# Copying Ubuntu partition from a dual boot machine to bootable USB flash drive

Tags: ubuntu, clonezilla, dualboot

I have a computer in dual boot configuration (Windows an Linux). I would like to clone only the Linux partition to USB flash drive and make it bootable in another computer. Can this be done? I tried to use Clonezilla to clone the Linux partition to a USB flash drive, but it looks like that did not make it bootable. Is there a possibility of doing it without cloning the entire drive?

UPDATE: With some probably very dangerous experimentation, I achieved something. I split the USB flash drive into two partition, I cloned my Linux partition onto one partition and EFI partition which contains grub bootloader I assume, on other partition.

I could then boot into the grub menu from USB flash drive on another computer. The boot options in the grub menu were the same as on the original computer. If I then tried to boot into Ubuntu recovery mode and selected update grub, I managed to boot into my Linux partition from the USB flash drive.

Comment: Learn rsync and how to install and configure bootloader (which includes knowing the firmware types and how booting works on the ones that you need the drive to boot on)

Comment: Also fstab and `root=` kernel parameter

Comment: “However, it works very slow, with 30 second delay for everything. So the issue is not really solved.” Yes. Your USB flash drive is most likely very slow. Your problem is clearly solved, but the speed issue can’t magically go away unless you yourself get a fast USB flash drive to use. There is not trick to this. Cloning data and making that data accessible in a fast and speedy way are two different things.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the feedback.